# Issue placing image into Photoshop from iCloud Drive

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icloud

So, I store a lot of images on my iCloud drive, more often than not when I try to drag these image files into photoshop I get the following error: "Could not place “.imageName.jpg.icloud” because no parser or file format can open the file" (See Image). Note, this doesn't happen with every image. I've discovered a workaround where if I open the image in preview first, it will then work with Photoshop. Is there a way to prevent this. I'm working with hundreds of images a day, and the added step of opening in 'Preview' is really slowing me down.

[image: Photoshop Error Message]

Comment: Have you tried copying the files to the local file system before attempting to open them?  Yes.. I know.. another step..

Comment: Yes, that works. If I copy/paste the file to desktop -or- open it in Preview it will work. The file momentarily disappears from iCloud and then reappears like it's been redownloaded. After this, I can drag the file directly from iCloud into Photoshop without a problem. This is odd, because it appears the file is initially already downloaded locally. I hope there's a quicker way.

Comment: .icloud is not an image format.  It is probably an internal format Apple uses to either compress or secure the data.. You have a finder extension that converts from this format to whatever it was supposed to be when moved locally.  Some Apple Fanboy should help us out here.. (I am not).. but I am sure about how a shell plugin works ;)

Comment: See here: https://faq.pdfviewer.io/en/articles/3914738-unable-to-open-files-with-pdf-icloud-extension

Comment: @1NN Thanks for the article, I will give this a shot. Do you know if there is a way to quickly download the original file without opening it? For example, 'right-click, download'. I know if the iCloud icon appears you can click on it to download, but I don't see any cloud icons.

Comment: I don't have a Mac. Maybe this question has a better chance of being answered on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Adding the column 'Kind' to Finder allows me to see if the file is an alias (not downloaded) or another filetype (downloaded). With the preview pane open I can download the image simply by clicking the iCloud download icon next to the filename.

[image: Finder View]